# What are disadvantages of using fun as a scope

Tags: macros, erlang

I wrote a macro like the following for concise logging:

```
-define(MY_MACRO(Expr, Params),
    case Expr of
        {correct_return, X} -> X;
        Result -> io:format("Unexpected result (~p:~p): ~p", [ ?MODULE, ?LINE, [
            {expr, ??Expr, Result},
            {params, ??Params, Params}
        ]]),
        undefined
    end).
```

But faced an error `variable 'Result' unsafe in case` when using it twice in the same scope. The following code solves my problem, but I wonder about its drawback.

```
-define(MY_MACRO(Expr, Params), (fun() ->
    case Expr of
        {correct_return, X} -> X;
        Result -> io:format("Unexpected result (~p:~p): ~p", [ ?MODULE, ?LINE, [
            {expr, ??Expr, Result},
            {params, ??Params, Params}
        ]]),
        undefined
    end end)()).
```

Or maybe, is there better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second solution is probably the best possible.  Since all the code is inside a fun, you don't introduce any new variable bindings, and avoid many surprises.  (If your original code had used `X` instead of `Result` in the second case clause, you wouldn't have gotten that error, but the second macro instantiation would match against the *first* result.)

By the way, your macro looks very similar to eunit's `assertEqual` macro.  You could use that straight away, or take its definition from `eunit.hrl` and modify it for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `begin…end` instead of `(fun () -> … end)()`.

- I believe it is a scoping issue. I'm not sure `begin…end`'s scoping behaves the sane as `fun`'s.
- I am not sure creating a fun only to call it afterwards is something the compiler optimises, but I have seen discussion about it.
- [This should interest you.](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/3011d16bfcff0dbdd369d4701751ab106dde100f)

Comment: I've just checked. `begin ... end` doesn't create new scope. But the link is useful. Thanks.

Comment: just use `begin...end`